# Assembly for loop -> for(i = -n; i < n; i++)

Tags: assembly, for-loop

Can anyone help me with writing a simple example of the for loop in assembly language for this code:

```
for (i = -n; i < n; ++i)
{
   ...
}
```

where  n != 0
I can't find any example of how to write a for loop where the loop doesn't start from 0.
So far I have this structure

```
mov ax, n
mov cx, n
neg cx

cmp cx, ax
JGE ENDFOR01 
DO01:
; output
LOOP DO01
ENDFOR01:
```

Comment: Sure, what do you have so far?  Where does it work and where does it fail?

Comment: I am beginner in assembly. I need to write a simple for loop as a template. Assuming that I have a variable n and I need to output in a for loop (I know how to do it in other types of loop) values of -n, -n+1 -n+2 ... n-1. Just for the sake of example lets say that I have a variable n which stores some value n, and value m which stores -n, and i need to iterate from -n to n. I doesn't, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: This is assembly, you can do it any way you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider a "long hand" way of writing it in C:

```
i = -n;
loop:
  if (!(i < n))
    goto end;
  ...
  ++i;
  goto loop;
end:
```

Hope that gives some insights!

Comment: The thing is that I know how to do it using the simple loop form, my problem is how to convert it in a for-loop form. I edited my question after you posted your answer and a bit explained it more detailed. Thank you

Comment: But, what do you think is a for-loop? It's an init, a condition and a step(size) and that's what pst tried to show you. Translate line by line and you are finished =)